# How to export module in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I would like to export Vuex module like below:

```
export {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

but when I am trying to include it in my index file it throws error. Something with types incompatibility. I think I should specify type of above object but I do not know what type it is.

```
import * as itemsModule from './app/store/items/module'

let store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        items: itemsModule
    }
});
```

throws:

> is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreOptions<{}>'.
>     Types of property 'modules' are incompatible.

Regards

Comment: Is this first export exporting objects ?  like `state: {..myStates}` and so on. Assuming that you are exporting the proper state, mutations, actions and getters I can't see why would raise this. Can you paste the rest of the code for the module ?  I used to export the module as default with `export default { state: {}, ...}` I don't know how the `as itemsModule` is behaving, maybe that's causing the incompatibility. Try to inspect how itemsModule looks like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are importing and exporting is not correct.
Try it that way:

**module.js**

```
export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

**store.js**

```
import itemsModule from './app/store/items/module'
```

***explanation:***
 the way you were importing the module, you got this kind of object:

```
{
  default: {
    actions: {/** ... */}
    getters: {/** ... */}
    mutations: {/** ... */}
    state: {/** ... */}
  }
}
```

which is not the structure the store is expecting for a module.